# Как в codeigniter с помощью ajax загружать картинки на сервер?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

Пример без ajax

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Форма загрузки</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php echo $error;?>

<?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');?>

<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />

<br /><br />

<input type="submit" value="upload" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Контроллер

class Upload extends Controller {

```
function Upload()
{
    parent::Controller();
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
}

function index()
{   
    $this->load->view('upload_form', array('error' => ' ' ));
}

function do_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    }   
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
    }
}
```

}
?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообщим решил вопрос
форма:

```
 <form role="form" action="">
                    <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <label for="title">Заголовок</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" required="" placeholder="Введіть Заголовок">
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="form-group">
                        <label for="brief_description">Короткий текст (початок)</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="brief_description" name="brief_description" maxlength="160"></textarea>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="form-group">
                        <label for="brief_description">Повний текст (продовження)</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="full_description" name="full_description" ></textarea>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="form-group">
                        <label for="InputFile">File input</label>
                        <input type="file" id="InputFile" name="image" multiple="multiple" size="20">
                        <div class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</div>
                        <button type="button" name="send_img" id="send_img" value="Send_img" class="btn btn-labeled btn-success">
                            <span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>Завантажити</button>
                    </fieldset>
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <button type="button" name="send_data" id="send_data" value="Send" class="btn btn-labeled btn-success">
                            <span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>Зберегти</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

js:

```
$("#InputFile").on("change", function(){
               files = this.files;
               //alert(file);

            });
            $('#send_img').click(function( event ){
                    event.stopPropagation(); // Остановка происходящего
                    event.preventDefault();  // Полная остановка происходящего

                    // Создадим данные формы и добавим в них данные файлов из files

                    var data = new FormData();
                    $.each( files, function( key, value ){
                        data.append( key, value );
                    });

                    // Отправляем запрос

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "<?=base_url()?>news/upload_photo",
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: data,
                        cache: false,
                        dataType: 'html',
                        processData: false, // Не обрабатываем файлы (Don't process the files)
                        contentType: false, // Так jQuery скажет серверу что это строковой запрос
                        success: function( data ){
                            $(".help-block").empty().append(data);
                        },
                        error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                            console.log('ОШИБКИ AJAX запроса: ' + textStatus );
                        }
                    });
                });
```

функция в контролере:

```
public function upload_photo(){

        if(isset($_FILES)){
            //print_r($_FILES);
            $config['upload_path']          = './img/node/';
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size']             = 5000;
            $config['encrypt_name']         = TRUE;

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->initialize($config);

            $this->upload->do_upload('0');
            $data = $this->upload->data();
            $html = '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Файл: '.$data['orig_name'].' успішно завантаженний! '."<p><br><img src='".base_url().'/img/node/'.$data['file_name']."'></p></div>";
            //print_r($data);
            echo $html;
        }
    }
```